# Synergy Key Mapping

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keymap, synergy

I'm running a Synergy server on Ubuntu and a Synergy+ client on OSX.   The server has a standard windows keyboard with <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>windows</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys.  My MacBookPro has <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>alt/option</kbd>, and <kbd>command</kbd> keys.

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, etc., the appropriate copy/paste action doesn't happen on the Mac, but it does in Ubuntu.  If I'm controlling the mac, and press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then I get the copy/paste action.

So I played around with key mapping in `synergy.conf` and found that the following allows me to do copy/paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>:

```
section: screens
    godzilla:
    mbp.local:
        ctrl = alt
        alt = ctrl
end
```

Is this all that I need to do?  Or are there other mappings that will help as well?  The [synergy configuration](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html) page refers to the following key mappings.  What are the equivalent keys for each of these on the Windows keyboard and Mac keyboard?  What is a meta or super key?

```
shift = {shift|ctrl|alt|meta|super|none}
ctrl = {shift|ctrl|alt|meta|super|none}
alt = {shift|ctrl|alt|meta|super|none}
meta = {shift|ctrl|alt|meta|super|none}
super = {shift|ctrl|alt|meta|super|none}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was in a similar situation at one point, and I found a somewhat 'unique' way around it.  Plug the keyboard directly into your Mac, and edit the keyboard preferences directly.  After that, any non-Apple keyboard you attach will use those mappings.

1. Plug in they keyboard.
2. Open System Preferences (Apple Menu -> System Preferences).
3. Enter "Keyboard" preferences (under Hardware).
4. From the "Keyboard Mapping" (or similarly named) tab, change the key mapping as you see fit.

Synergy+ will use these key mappings, since it identifies as a virtual keyboard.

EDIT:
Equivalent mappings, based on function:

```
Linux   │ Mac
────────┼─────────
Control │ Command
Alt     │ Control
Meta    │ Alt
Shift   │ Shift
Super   │ Super
```

Mac has the extra modifier key (kind of like the old EMACS-style keyboards, which had up to 5 modifier keys).  Super is generally deprecated, so you shouldn't have to worry about remapping it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this helps!  But I think I'm still not getting something right. Do you know what exact mappings should I use?  Could you provide me with the key mappings from your synergy.conf file so I can make sure to get this right?

Comment: Running the server on my Windows 7 instead of Linux, and these applied. The important thing to understand is that it seems like "Meta" is apple's "apple" key.

Answer (score 41):

For what it's worth, I finally took the time to figure out my Synergy mapping setup.

Linux server (desktop), OS X client (macbook). I wanted the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on desktop -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on macbook
- <kbd>WinKey</kbd> on desktop -> <kbd>Command/⌘</kbd> on macbook
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> on desktop -> <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> on macbook

This allows for the same keyboard mappings that my Hackintosh desktop keyboard uses, so keyboard shortcuts like copy/paste are still different between Linux and OS X, but I'm okay with that.

I used the following config:

```
section: screens
    desktop:
          # Linux server, no mapping
    batbook:
        # OS X client
        ctrl = ctrl
        alt = meta
        super = alt
        # meta = ??  # no idea where this shows up on the client end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Mapping super to alt is what I was looking for (I had been mapping meta to alt, which provides similar, but not quite the same functionality in OSX)

Comment: Thats it, `super = alt` did it!

Answer (score 11):

I have a mac full size keyboard plugged into my PC which is synergy server.

When connected to mac client (osX mountain lion), I've switched ctrl and commmand keys so that ctrl-c copies regardless of machine.

This is done in the synergy gui by double clicking the client and setting:

ctrl: Meta
meta: ctrl

I hope this helps!

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me in synergy 1.7.1

Answer (score 9):

As a PC user wanting to connect to OS X, you may find the following useful:

```
shift = shift
ctrl = meta
alt = ctrl
meta = super
super = alt
```

This will get you a setup where your usual cut / copy / paste will do what you want and the other keys will be available.

Mapping (Windows to Mac):

```
<Ctrl>   -> ⌘ (command) 
<WinKey> -> ⌥ (option / alt)
<Alt>    -> ⌃  (control)
```

Notes:

- Using Synergy v1.8.8
- Don't forget to fix your registry if you have disabled the windows key.  The On-Screen Keyboard is great for checking this.

Answer (score 5):

If you're used to a PC keyboard and want to control your Mac remotely without changing your setup, you map the remote Macintosh computer's keyboard configuration in Synergy with the following:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -> <kbd>Meta</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>

<kbd>Meta</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

<kbd>Super</kbd> -> <kbd>Super</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Super is the "Windows" key on most keyboards.  Meta is (I believe) the Esc key.

Comment: Meta is typically Alt, or Alt+Esc.

Comment: Ok.  I'm used to it being Esc from Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

This change, at least when serving *from* OSX (10.11) *to* Windows 10 is;

```
section: screens
  ClientNameHere:
    ctrl = super
    super = ctrl
```

*Note: If you're not using the synergy.conf file; configure the client by double clicking on the client in the layout screen.*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving this old question, but I found it relevant and useful for configuring my current setup. I thought I'd share my config for those interested.

Using a [Logitech G613](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.logitechg.com%2Fen-us%2Fproducts%2Fgaming-keyboards%2Fg613-wireless-mechanical-gaming-keyboard.html&psig=AOvVaw3cWxX-khbLxOHThOp6gdY8&ust=1624003004303000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJDq8OOYnvECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAF) keyboard on a macOS 11.23 (with CTRL - WINDOWS - ALT layout) to also control a Windows 10 laptop.

Here is my setup:
[Synergy and macOS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otc1w.png)

Help pages:

- [macOS keyboard modifier help](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/17/how-to-remap-windows-keyboard-buttons-match-mac-layout/)
- [Synergy modifier help](https://symless.com/help-articles/how-can-i-swap-modifier-keys)

I can easily use my copy/paste functionalities without having to use weird shortcuts on one of the 2 machines, beside the fact that it is a CTRL+C on Mac instead of COMMAND+C.